# Alternative set notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set $A = \{S_1, S_2,..., S_N\}$.
Each $S_x$ element of set $A$ is another set, such that:
$S_x = \{a\}$ or $S_x = \{a,b\}$ or $S_x = \{a,b,c\}$ or $S_x = \{a,b,c,d\}$.

I was wondering whether I could use an alternative notation for the internal sets, instead of curly brackets, without creating any confusion. For example, could I denote them as tuples (even though the order of the elements does not matter), i.e:
$S_x = (a)$ or $S_x = (a,b)$ or $S_x = (a,b,c)$ or $S_x = (a,b,c,d)$.

The problem is, in case I use the above tuple notation, would it be correct to use the $\in$ operator as $a \in S_x$?

Is there a better way to tackle this?

Please note that I need to use the $\in$ operator for the elements of the internal sets, e.g. $a \in S_x$.

Comment: Stay with curly brackets for sets. The tuple notation has another meaning.

Comment: What information do you want to convey in notation? Is that each of the $S_x$ has $1$ to $4$ elements?

Comment: When you say you want to use a different notation: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I could use the tuple notation $S_x = (a,b,c)$, as it does not affect the problem the fact that the elements in the tuple are ordered. My question is, if $y$ is an element in the tuple of $S_x$, how do I denote in an equation that $y$ belongs in $S_x$? Could I state that $y \in S_x$ or is it wrong to do so?